# Fxcop referrer existing rule in a custom rule project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, fxcop

I'm writing a custom fxcop rule to exclude some words from "**Identifiers Should Be Cased Correctly**" rule. What I want to do is, there are some words that I used in my project which are some notations I implemented, so once above rule meet those words I want to rule to skip that words from showing warnings (ignore that word).

**I want to do this by not adding the words into fxcop dictionary.**